# resize an RGB image using interp1 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is how i resize a greyscale image without using imresize(). But i cant apply the same code for a colour image, it made it greyscale. what do i need to change to resize a RGB image using the same method? thank you.

```
lighthouse_quarter = imread('lighthouse_quarter.png');
lighthouse_quarter = double(lighthouse_quarter);
[rows, columns] = size(lighthouse_quarter); % define rows and columns

for row = 1 :128 : rows
n = 1:128; %define row limits
x_quarter = (1:128); %original row limits
lh_rows_quarter = lighthouse_quarter(n,:); %value of columns at each row
xi_quarter = 1:0.25:128; %new row limits
lh1_quarter = interp1(x_quarter, lh_rows_quarter, xi_quarter, 'linear'); %interpolated row values

for column = 1 : 128 : columns
    m = 1:128; %define column limits
    y_quarter = (1:128); %original row limits
    lh_columns_quarter = lh1_quarter(:,m)'; %value of rows at each column  
    yi_quarter = (1:0.25:128); %new column limits
    lighthouse_quarter_linear = interp1(y_quarter, lh_columns_quarter, yi_quarter, 'linear'); %interpolated column values
end
end
```

Comment: Your image _lighthouse_quarter.png_ is grey or colored? Attach your image here.

Comment: the image lighthouse_quarter.png is gray but I want to apply the same method for a different, coloured image.

Comment: In that case...you need to add one more loop for each color....What's problem with yesterday's code?

Comment: have you looked at `interp2`? (for 2D data)

Comment: thank you again for yesterday code but i cant increase the size of the image with the yesterday code .  I tried and do it with one more loop and got this problem"The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values."

Comment: @Gelliant In this homework,I have to work with interp1.

Comment: If this is homework, you need to show a further attempt. This is not a webpage to make your homework

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm sorry, it seems that i have misused the function of this website. I will put more research into this, thanks.

Comment: @thanhthai If you are going to put more research in this first, you may consider deleting your question now and creating a new one later if you have a more specific question.